# Horizontal alignment of items in a list

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, alignment

I have a list with an accordion in react-native, made using the List package from react-native-paper. It works but I would like a helping hand to improve the aesthetic aspect.
As you can see in the screenshot below, the number of objects is not aligned with the other elements. Likewise, but this is a bonus, I would have liked the title to be centered, between quantity and price. And there it is a little complicated, I try to add styles but that does not apply.
I tried that in list.item and in list.accordion:

> style={{justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}

I would like to know if you can give me any leads, advice or your solution.

Thanks for any help

```
<List.Section title={item.created_at.substring(0, 10)} titleStyle={{fontSize: 16, color: '#013243'}} key={i.toString()}>
            <List.Accordion
              title={item.quote_number}
              style={{width: '98%'}}
              left={props => <List.Icon {...props} color={'#F78400'} icon={require('../../../assets/images/logo.png')} />}>
              <List.Item titleStyle={{color: '#F78400'}} title={`Total: ${item.amount} €`}/>
              {
                item.items.map((product, i) => (
                  <List.Item
                    title={product.name.substring(0, 30)}
                    titleStyle={{fontSize: 14}}
                    description={product.description}
                    descriptionStyle={{fontSize: 11}}
                    descriptionNumberOfLines={4}
                    key={i.toString()}
                    left={()=>(<Text>{product.quantity}</Text>)}
                    right={()=>(<Text>{product.cost} €</Text>)}
                  />
                ))
              }
            </List.Accordion>
          </List.Section>
```

[image: screencap]

Comment: You have lists nested inside each other which is bad practice. In the dom it probably looks like this <ul><li><li></li></li></ul> and the height issue has to do with the font sizes most likely. So you can either use a different component instead of a nested list item or try to edit the margins/padding/fontsize of the <Text> elements

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer, on the other hand we are not on html code but javascript, there is no div / li etc.

Comment: try using **style={{textAlign:'center'}}** for left and right **Text**

Comment: The libraries your using converts the List objects into JSX  elements and react renders those into actual html. Understanding the html structure being generated by your code can be important. For example, if you want to ensure your web pages are accessible or allow for test automation ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be corrected by applying style to the **left** and **right** props as follows:

```
<List.Item
title={product.name.substring(0, 30)}
titleStyle={{fontSize: 14}}
description={product.description}
descriptionStyle={{fontSize: 11}}
descriptionNumberOfLines={4}
key={i.toString()}
left={()=>(<Text style = {styles.textStyle}>{product.quantity}</Text>)} // styled
right={()=>(<Text style = {styles.textStyle}>{product.cost} €</Text>)} // styled
/>

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
    textStyle: {
        marginTop: 4, // you may adjust this value according to your requirement
        fontSize: 14,
    }

})
```

Comment: Yes, but the marginTop: 4 is something that depends on the height of the container item and it does not give the same result every time

Comment: You're right @NickPantelidism, but the reason for this style issue is that the parent view of the listitem 'title' component is given marginVertical hardcoded in the plugin source file and there are no props available to style this parent-element. That's why I just gave marginTop: 4 to the text element to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily adding the proper style in every item. Check the bellow snippet. In this way you align vertically the number of objects and also the title is centered.

```css
.product {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>Product 1 title</div>
  <div>234.54$</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to answer, on the other hand we are not on html code but javascript, there is no div / li etc.

Comment: I know that it is not html but I wrote this example to show you the style that you can use in order to achieve what you want

Comment: Yes, thank you, I follow you and use ' style={{justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}} ' but it doesn't apply

Comment: You must also add display: 'flex'. I am looking forward to tell me about the result